# Prevent URLs from specific domains from being saved in Firefox history

Tags: firefox, history

I want to prevent or block URLs of specific domains from being saved or shown in my history. I want to be able to go to these certain websites normally, just not have them saved and not have to use private or incognito mode.

For instance, I don't want any of Google's search result pages to be saved in my history since then when I use the awesomebar I get a lot of Google's search results, which are of no use to me.

Of course I can keep on deleting them, but I would like a way to specify that any URL starting with www.google.com shouldn't be saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still have yet to explore how this can be done manually.
But for now you can use [**HistoryBlock**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8631) Addon. I believe it answers your requirements.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dwarf -- that's exactly what I was looking for....

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should help:

1. [HistoryBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/historyblock/):

   [image: 1]
2. [History Deleter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/history-deleter/):

   [image: 2]