# Prevent certain URLs and anything referring from them from going to the Firefox history

Tags: firefox, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent urls from specific domains from being saved in firefox’s history](https://superuser.com/questions/53756/prevent-urls-from-specific-domains-from-being-saved-in-firefoxs-history)

Without using <strike>Porn</strike>Private Browsing Mode, is there a way to prevent Firefox from saving URLs matching a certain pattern (e.g. `reddit.com/r/WTF/*`) to the history? Preferably anything with a referrer of such an URL should also not be recorded in the history.

Obviously this is not possible natively, but maybe there's an extension that allows it...